# panda dataframe: How to pick a columns after using agregate and groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used the following code `dfp2=dfp1[dfp1.Typ=="Obligo"].groupby("Datum")["Wert"].sum()` and get the following result for dfp2:

```
Datum
2020-02-04    4415040.0
2020-02-19    4363270.0
2020-03-03    4218410.0
2020-04-02    3519220.0
Name: Wert, dtype: float64
```

Now I want to plot the number and the date. But I can't use `dfp2["Datum"]` to get the dates (`KeyError: 'Datum'`) and the values don't even have a column name. How do I select the columns? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `dfp2=dfp1[dfp1.Typ=="Obligo"].groupby("Datum", as_index=False)["Wert"].sum()`?

Comment: Maybe this will help. `dfp2=dfp1[dfp1.Typ=="Obligo"].groupby("Datum")["Wert"].sum().reset_index()`.